# average revenue per user increases each country but decreases when combined

Tags: hypothesis-testing, experiment-design, descriptive-statistics, simpsons-paradox

I'm trying to figure out what could be some reasons when we do the AB testing we're seeing average revenue per user increases for each country but when we calculate the overall average revenue per user( combine total revenue/total users), the metric decreases...

Answer (score 15):

This phenomenon is called Simpson's Paradox, but it's not really paradoxical.

The likely explanation is that you are getting more users in lower-revenue countries.

Toy example:

- Before:

  - In Cheapia: revenue \$1000, users 100:  \$/user =10
  - In Luxuristan: revenue \$1000, users 10: \$/user =100
  - total \$/user: \$18
- Now

  - In Cheapia: revenue \$20000, users 1500: \$/user=13
  - In Luxuristan: revenue \$2000, users 10: \$/user=200
  - total \$/user: \$15

The total revenue and \$/user has gone up in both countries but the overall $/user has gone down because you've had high growth in the lower-revenue country

Comment: +1 I read the title and thought, "Isn't this exactly what Simpson's paradox is?" $//$ I find [this animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox#/media/File:Simpsons_paradox_-_animation.gif) on Wikipedia to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The algebra is as follows:

Let $R_1, R_2$ be revenues per country, $R= R_1+R_2$, $N_1, N_2$ be population per country, $N= N_1 + N_2$, and write the per capita magnitudes as
$$r_1 = \frac{R_1}{N_1},\quad r_2 = \frac{R_2}{N_2},$$

and population proportions
$$n_1 = \frac{N_1}{N}, \quad n_2 = \frac{N_2}{N}.$$

Then the overal per capita revenue can be written
\begin{align}
r &= \frac {R}{N} = \frac{R_1+R_2}{N} = \frac{R_1}{N_1}\cdot \frac{N_1}{N} = \frac{R_2}{N_2}\cdot \frac{N_2}{N}\\
&= r_1\cdot n_1 + r_2\cdot n_2
\end{align}

So the change in the overall per capita revenue is
\begin{align}
\Delta(r) = \Delta (r_1\cdot n_1 + r_2\cdot n_2) &= r_1\Delta(n_1) + n_1\Delta(r_1) + \Delta(n_1)\Delta(r_1) \\
&\;\;\; + r_2\Delta(n_2) + n_1\Delta(r_2) + \Delta(n_2)\Delta(r_2).
\end{align}

We see that the change in the overall per capita metric depends on much more than just the change in the country-specific per capita revenues: it also depends on the change of the relative weight of each country in determining the overall metric, as well as in the interaction of the two changes per country. Anything goes.